# pandas dataframe transformation partial sums

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

index A

```
1    3.4
2    4.5
3    5.3
4    2.1
5    4.0
6    5.3
...
95   3.4
96   1.2
97   8.9
98   3.4
99   2.7
100  7.6
```

from this I would like to create a dataframe B

```
 1-5    sum(1-5)
 6-10   sum(6-10) 
 ...
 96-100 sum(96-100)
```

Any ideas how to do this elegantly rather than brute-force?

Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a series with the partial sums:

```
df['bin'] = df.index / 5
bin_sums = df.groupby('bin')['A'].sum()
```

Then, if you want to rename the index:

```
bin_sums.index = ['%s - %s' % (5*i, 5*(i+1)) for i in bin_sums.index]
```